# Blackberry: Application Back up

Tags: blackberry

I want to store all the third party application and after the wipe the device i want to again restore all the third party application that are installed on my device. IS there is any API available for this kind of application backup in Blackberry.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the BB Desktop Manager does already?

Comment: But i want to do it programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a scripting language to build this kind of functionality using JavaLoader which is provided by the development environment.

Comment: can you tell me how i use that language along with java loader.

Comment: JavaLoader has the ability to copy software off the BlackBerry onto a PC. See the documentation for JavaLoader on how to do that. Then pick a scripting language supported on you platform that you like and write your program. If you need more detailed instructions then that you have probably picked a project that is too advanced for your current level of knowledge.